# how to choose tdengine's normal table and stable?

Tags: tdengine

I used tdengine for a few weeks, i felt confused about stable and normal table.
How to choose between normal table and stable?
Does someone have expeirence on choosing between normal table and stable.

Answer (score 0):

If you have many child tables which share the same structure/schema, you can create a stable as the model of this schema which is also the parent of normal child tables.